# How to import Shell script output (Comma separated File) into Splunk Index

Tags: bash, splunk, splunk-query

I have bash script that generates comma separated file. I want to trigger the script from splunk and convert its output into splunk index.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the manual page on Splunk, in this [section](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/blog/tips-and-tricks/working-with-spreadsheets-in-splunk-excel-csv-files.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20import,lookup%20file%20into%20the%20view.), you can see how to Editing and Importing your CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

Create a monitor input for the file.  When Splunk sees new data is written to the file it will read it in automatically.  If the file is not on the same system as Splunk then you can install the Splunk Universal Forwarder to monitor the file and send the data to Splunk.